# get all values from SQL column using PHP (only returns one value)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am querying the database for all values in one column, then putting it into an associative array. The db query is working, but PHP prints an array with only one item.

```
<?php
$acc_names = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT acc_name FROM accounts"); #successfully returns all values in column in mysql
$acc_names = (mysqli_fetch_assoc($acc_names));

print_r($acc_names);              #only one item in array
print_r($acc_names['acc_name']);  #that one item
?>
```

Comment: You should use `mysqli_fetch_all($acc_names, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: that did the job. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `mysqli_fetch_all($acc_names, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.